# How to send 3 transactions to 3 different testnets in brownie

Tags: python, testnets, brownie

I'm trying send 3 transactions on python (using brownie as api) to 3 different testnets (kovan, rinkeby and goerli), and i'm doing this using 3 differents threads.

I have already import inside of thread the network of brownie, like this:

```
import brownie.network as network_
```

And, inside of a thread i'm doing this:

```
def addFileBlockChain(add, testnet, filename, text):
  import brownie.network as network_

  if network_.is_connected():
    network_.disconnect()
  
  network_.connect(testnet)

  if testnet == "kovan":
    dev = network_.accounts.add(os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY_K'))
  elif testnet == "goerli":
    dev = network_.accounts.add(os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY_G'))
  else:
    dev = network_.accounts.add(os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY_R'))

 contract = TxtFileShare.at(add)
 contract.addFile(filename, text, {'from': dev})
```

But, only 1 thread works, the others raise exceptions like this:
"ConnectionError: No active network"
"Already connected to network 'rinkeby'"

Using brownie we can't connect to various networks simultaneously? If yes, how (using import on python)?

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone? I really need some help.

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Python 3.8.10 ...